# Connection Timeout and Connection Lifetime

Tags: timeout, connection, connection-pooling, lifetime

What is the advantage and disadvantage of connection timeout=0?

And what is the use of Connection Lifetime=0?

e.g

```
(Database=TestDB;
 port=3306;
 Uid=usernameID;
 Pwd=myPassword;
 Server=192.168.10.1;
 Pooling=false;
 Connection Lifetime=0;
 Connection Timeout=0)
```

and what is the use of Connection Pooling?

Answer (score 44):

Timeout is how long you wait for a response from a request before you give up. TimeOut=0 means you will keep waiting for the connection to occur forever. Good I guess if you are connecting to a really slow server that it is normal if it takes 12 hours to respond :-). Generally a bad thing. You want to put some kind of reasonable timeout on a request, so that you can realize your target is down and move on with your life.

**Connection Lifetime** = how long a connection lives before it is killed and recreated. A lifetime of 0 means never kill and recreate. Normally not a bad thing, because killing and recreating a connection is slow. Through various bugs your connections may get stuck in an unstable state (like when dealing with weird 3 way transactions).. but 99% of the time it is good to keep connection lifetime as infinite.

**Connection pooling** is a way to deal with the fact that creating a connection is very slow. So rather than make a new connection for every request, instead have a pool of say, 10, premade connections. When you need one, you borrow one, use it, and return in. You can adjust the size of the pool to change how your app behaves. Bigger pool = more connections = more threads doing stuff at a time, but this could also overwhelm whatever you are doing.

In summary: 
**ConnectionTimeout=0** is bad, make it something reasonable like 30 seconds. 
**ConnectionLifetime=0** is okay 
**ConnectionPooling=disabled** is bad, you will likely want to use it.

Comment: May I know if you have any idea on how this error came-up?
'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

Comment: Your server isn't responding. Could be down, could not be open on the right port, could be a firewall, etc. Need more details

Comment: I like the more verbose desc of ConnectionLifetime then mysql documentation.

Comment: Is there any reason not to set min number of connection to be same as max number of connection in pool? we are facing an issue when on spike number of HTTP requests, we are probably creating a lot of HTTP connections which is slow as you said and move it to unhealthy state)

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old thread but I think it is important to point out an instance in which you may want to disable Connection Pooling or use Connection Lifetime.

In some environments (especially when using Oracle, or at least in my experience) the web application is designed so that it connects to the database using the user's credentials vs a fixed connection string located in the server's configuration file. In this case enabling connection pooling will cause the server to create a connection pool for each user accessing the website (See [Pool Fragmentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)). Depending on the scenario this could either be good or bad.

However, **connection pooling becomes a problem** when the database server is configured to kill database connections that exceed a maximum idle time due to the fact that the database server could kill connections that may still reside in the connection pool. In this scenario the **Connection Lifetime** may come in handy to throw away these connections since they have been closed by the server anyway.