# Set connection lifetime in WSO2 ESB nhttp transport

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there a way to set the connection lifetime (time to be active regardless of the usage) in WSO2 nhttp transport?

Answer (score 1):

as Bhathiya says, nhttp.properties is the way to configure the nhttp timeout "globally".

You can also use a specific timeout in one of your endpoints definition

If you want a timeout value over 120 seconds, don't forget to set "synapse.global_timeout_interval" in synapse.properties

Comment: Socket timeout will be refreshed for each data packet it received. But What I wanted here to have a hard stop for a connection to be used after a defined time. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748706/connection-timeout-and-connection-lifetime

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Configuring+nhttp.properties) socket timeouts in `repository/conf/nhttp.properties` file, if that's what you're looking for.

```
# Client > ESB Connection timeout
http.socket.timeout.receiver=180000
# ESB > BackEnd Connection timeout
http.socket.timeout.sender=180000
```

Comment: @Bathiya, Socket timeout will be refreshed for each data packet it received. But What I wanted here to have a hard stop for a connection to be used after a defined time. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748706/connection-timeout-and-connection-lifetime