# I need to download data that MySQL can not process because of amount

Tags: mysql, spring-batch, large-data

I'm trying to download data from MySQL (5.7.22-22-log) via Spring Batch.
There are about 200 million rows.
The problems are

1. if I download even 100M rows it takes ~12 minutes, which is too long Spring Batch fails with something like

> HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected

or

> HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@7fece665 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

2. if I download all rows then mysql ends up with message after some time

> Killed

Now I'm trying simply download a column with id-s, but in fact I need add a couple of join-s and it does not look like simplification for the query.

How it can be solved in general?

Maybe I can download partially? Well I already use parameters fetch size and chunk size, but I guess they are applied after a query is executed where my query can not be executed yet.

I mean download partially and do it manually like select data with this interval of id-s, then next etc.

But I have a cron job, which should do the whole work.
I should somehow schedule subroutines and merge results.

Maybe there are more advanced techniques?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can increase the timeout of the MySQL Database. 
I found this Link.
[Increase MySQL Timeout](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server/)

Answer (score 0):

A chunk oriented step with a reasonable chunk size is the way to go. However, you need to make sure MySQL connection life time is set correctly in order for MySQL server to not kill your connection. You can find more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748741/5019386